# Which particles to include in loop corrections to maintain gauge invariance

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I have been reading both Peskin and Schröder and Schwartz's QFT books, in particular the sections in each book regarding precision tests of the standard model where they calculate loop corrections to the gauge bosons. (Schwartz pg 649, peskin pg 760). Both claim that if one is to consider the top quark contributions, one must also include the bottom quark contribution in order to maintain gauge invariance. I do not understand why this is true. I am wondering if this is manifest from the Lagrangian somehow, or if this is a matter of how certain contributions that violate gauge invariance cancel if the whole doublet is considered, and why this might be the case.

Thanks!

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which pages?

Comment: Schwartz pg 649, peskin pg 760

Comment: The $t_L$ and $b_L$ are part of the same $SU(2)$ doublet so both will appear in the polarizations of the gauge bosons at one-loop. For example, the $W^+ W^-$ 2-point function has both top and bottom running in the one-loop contribution.

Comment: this part I understand, but why does this guarantee gauge invariance. This seems more like an argument that one must include them simply because they both appear in the Lagrangian in a certain form for charged currents